# How to get deleted row count?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my windows batch file, I execute an sql which contains a query that deletes rows if fits the condition which means that it deleted unwanted rows of data. Assuming that the sql execution has no errors, is there any way to obtain the count of deleted rows?

The purpose of this is so that I can log if there are deleted rows.

```
IF DELETED_ROWS_COUNT > 0 (
   echo Some invalid rows are DELETED.
)
```

This is how I executed the sql file.

```
psql -h %DB_HOST% -p 5432 -U %DB_USER% -d %DB_NAME% -q -f "%HOME%\bin\import.sql" 2>> "%importfilename%"
```

Or if you have any other approach that is more doable than this idea, it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: and yet another option is to put the logic into pgplsql and use either Craig's suggested CTE or just `GET DIAGNOSTICS row_count := NOW_COUNT`

Answer (score 1):

One option is to get the deleted tuple count using a writeable CTE, e.g.

```
with del as (delete from a returning id) select count (*) from del;
```

AFAIK `psql` doesn't offer any easy way to get the affected-rows count without parsing the command-tag output like

```
DELETE 8
```

from the standard output.

Also, I suggest using `psql -qAtX` to run in quiet tuples-only mode with no headers/formatting, and ignore any `psqlrc`.